# How to change default codepage in Windows Terminal using WSL?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal

I have a file saved as a `Big5` encoding. I have to use `cp950` codepage to show that text successfully.

In Command Prompt, I can use `CHCP 950` to switch to right codepage. In WSL, I don't know how to do that. Anyone know?

This screenshot shows I can use `iconv` convert encoding from `cp950` to `utf8`. The text will show on screen correctly. But I need to show `cp950` to the output directly.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you run `chcp 950` in WSL?

Comment: Thanks for moving this over from Stack Exchange.  I've had zero success with this so far, and it's bugging me too now.  I would have thought that `chcp.com 950` from within WSL would work, but a subsequent `chcp.com` still shows it at 437.  Note that a `Get-Content` from PowerShell doesn't honor the Windows codepage either.  It still requires a `Get-Content -Encoding 950 filename` in order to display correctly, even though `chcp` shows 950.

Comment: I think it's Terminal's problem.

Comment: @WillHuang Agreed - If you haven't already, I would recommend opening an issue on the [Windows Terminal Github](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal).  If you have (or when you do), link it back here on this question in case anyone else comes looking for information on it.  Thanks!

Comment: @WillHuang I noticed the latest preview build includes a setting where *"you can now select a different default display language for Terminal in the Appearance settings"*.  Unfortunately this only seems to impact the UI language of menus/etc.